# How to change the specific japanese font style?

Tags: japanese

How to change the specific japanese font style ?

```
        \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{CJKutf8}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
    \section{これは最初のセクションである}
    日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

    フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
    \end{CJK*}

    \bigskip

    Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.

    \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{goth}
    \section{これは最初のセクションである}
    I want to change the japanese font style of this number 2?
    \end{CJK*}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I run code below on Windows 10, TeX Live 2022 with `xelatex`. And you should download the fonts from [Index of /adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/OTF/Japanese/](https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/OTF/Japanese/) and [Index of /adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/OTF/Japanese/](https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/OTF/Japanese/). Install these fonts for all users by right click on these `otf` font files.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setCJKmainfont{Source Han Serif}
\setCJKsansfont{Source Han Sans}
\setCJKsansfont{Source Han Serif}
\begin{document}
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本语で \LaTeX の组版を実証するための导入部分。
フォントはまた、数学的な形态および他の环境で使用することができる

Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
I want to change the japanese font style of this number 2?

\sffamily
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本语で \LaTeX の组版を実証するための导入部分。
フォントはまた、数学的な形态および他の环境で使用することができる

Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
I want to change the japanese font style of this number 2?

\ttfamily
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本语で \LaTeX の组版を実証するための导入部分。
フォントはまた、数学的な形态および他の环境で使用することができる

Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
I want to change the japanese font style of this number 2?
\end{document}
```

[image]